# What is the proper php.ini path and what should I put in it?

Tags: php, macos, installation, php-ini

I just managed to install the latest php version using this guide

[*Upgrading the Native PHP Installation on OS X Mountain Lion* (Aug 2012 by Bruno Skvorc)](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) and now I wonder should the `php.ini` file be located.

When I am at the terminal and I give the command `php --ini` I get the following path :

```
/usr/local/lib
```

When I execute phpinfo() in a script I get the following php.ini path :

```
/etc
```

Where should I put `php.ini` file and what should I put in it?

Comment: http://php.net/configuration.file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php -ini shows the location of the binary's .ini file (ie calling PHP not through a browser) 
phpinfo() shows the location of the version used by the server (ie calling PHP through a browser)

I dont know what you want in there, the ini file allows you to customize php to your use of php. I dont know what you want out of it ?

Comment: I would add that the location of that file is a matter of preference, but it usually makes sense to leave it at the default.  It makes it easier to find when the next guy has to deal with your server.

Comment: Agreed, If you absolutely NEED a new location for the files use a symbolic link http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001110610290643

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer, but I am still confused.Can you give me an example? (ie where is php.ini in your system)

Comment: It should already be there.  Just follow the paths mentioned in your question.  You'll find a file there called php.ini.  This file is used to set configuration defaults for PHP at run time including, but not limited to max execution time, max memory usage, and default include paths.

Comment: In fact the was no php.ini file in the system after php installation.

Comment: I just copied php.ini.default to from /etc to /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: the one @ /etc is the one used when people view your server. which is likely to be 99%+ of the time php is used. The php binary is useful for running mail forwards to php scripts etc